# Relation of order

Tags: abstract-algebra, relations

Lets consider N-{0} and the relation of order a|b (a divides b).

Lets consider the subset {1,2,...,10}.

I found {(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5), (1,6), (1,7),(1,8),(1,9),(1,10), (2,2),(2,4),(2,8),(3,3),(3,6),(3,9),(4,4),(4,8),(5,5),(5,10),(6,6),(7,7),(8,8),(9,9),(10,10)}

I am confused. How can i order them by knowing this. For example if you give me numbers i can order them using inequalitys, if you give me sets i can use inclusion to order them. In this case, on a line, who stands before and who stands after? How do i know?

Moreover, i have to show inf=GCD
and sup=lcm

GCD: for each n in E GCD divides n,
for each k in the minors set k divides GCD

1. The set of minors of E is the set of the common divisors of all the elements of E
2. GCD is the multiple of all common divisors, than it is GCD

Comment: What's MCD and mcm? I am not a native speaker and I failed looking up what these acronymes mean.

Comment: Gcd and lcm  : greatest common divisor and least common multiple

Comment: If you understand ordering of sets by inclusion, then ordering numbers by divisibility isn't too different. Note that neither of these orders is [total](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order), i.e. they don't place elements "on a line".

Comment: It's not a *total* order. Not any two elements can be compared.  You can not for example compare $3$ to $7$ or $4$ to $6$.   So there is no line that every one can be in.  There are the following lines:  1-2-4-8 (that's the longest line BTW) 1-2-6; 1-2-10; 1-3-6; 1-3-9; 1-5-10; 1-7;  And you make a graph diagram (which I can't type) where $1$ is the smallest element.  There are four elements that are larger than $1$ of which there are no smaller elements other than $1$ (there are 2,3,5,7) but do not compare to each other.  Then there are elements larger than those $4>2;6>2$ and $6>3;9>3$ etc.

Comment: You missed $(2,6)$ and $(2,10)$,

Answer (score -1):

> {(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5), (1,6), (1,7),(1,8),(1,9),(1,10), (2,2),(2,4),(2,8),(3,3),(3,6),(3,9),(4,4),(4,8),(5,5),(5,10),(6,6),(7,7),(8,8),(9,9),(10,10)}

That is it.  That is all there is to the order.

> How can i order them by knowing this. For example if you give me numbers i can order them using inequalitys

You can't.  It's not a *total* order.  Not any two numbers can be compared.  You can not campare $2$ to $3$ or $8$ to $6$ and any pair not in you list.

> In this case, on a line, who stands before and who stands after?

There is no line there is a mesh:  I'm not sure I'll be able to format this right be I will try:

$\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}   
&&2&\xrightarrow{}&4&\xrightarrow{}8\\
&\nearrow{}&&\searrow{}&&&\\
&\xrightarrow{}&3&\xrightarrow{}&6&&\\
1&&&\searrow{}&&&\\
&\xrightarrow{}&5&&9&&\\
&\searrow{}&&\searrow{}&&&\\
&&7&&10&&\\
\end{array} $

As you can see we have only four incomplete lines.

$1< 2 < 4 < 8$

$1< 2 < 6$

$1< 3< 6$

$1< 3 < 9$

$1 < 5 < 10$

$1< 7$.

====

> i have to show inf=GCD and sup=lcm

Well that follows by definition.  $d=\inf S$ must be a lower bound of $S$.  That means it must be "$\le$" to every element of $S$.  That means it must be a natural number that divides every element of $S$.  That means it must be a common divisor of $S$.  And it must be the *greatest* lower bound which means if $g> d$ then $g$ is not a lower bound.  In other words if $d|g$ then there exists an $e\in S$ so that $g\not < e$ or in other words $g \not \mid e$.  Thus $d$ is a common divisor so that if $d|g; d\ne g$ then $g$ is *not* a common divisor.  That is the definition of $\gcd(S)$.

In this case that $\inf\{1,2,3,...,10\}$ is clearly $1$.  In a less trivial example if $S = \{6,8\}$ then $\inf S \le 6$ and $\inf S \le 8$.  Then values that are the $< 6$ are those that divide $6$ or $1,2,3,6$ and the values that are $< 8$ are those that divide $8$ or $1,2,4,8$.  SO $\inf S = 1$ or $2$.  As $2> 1$ (because $1|2$) and $2$ is a lower bound $\inf S \ne 1$. So $\inf S = 2$ (if it exists).  If $g> 2$ (that is if $2|g$ then $g = 2^am$.  If $a > 1$ then $2^am\not \mid 6$ and if $m > 1;m$ odd, then $2^am \not \mid 8$ so $g> 2 \implies g$ is not a lower bound so $\inf S = 2$.

Similar argument to show that $\sup S$ is $\text{lcm} S$.  $\text{lcm} S$ must be a number larger or equal to all $S$, i.e. a number all elements of $S$ divide into, i.e. a common multiple, but one where any number that other then itself that can divide into it, is not a common multiple.  I.e. $\sup S = \text{lcm} S$.

$m=\sup \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\} = 2^3\cdot 3^2\cdot 5 \cdot 7 = 2520$.

It must be that $10 \le m$ so $10|m$.  And we must have $9\le m$ so $9|m$ and $7\le m$ so $7|m$ and $8\le m$ so $8|m$.  And that requires $m$ be a multiple of $2520$. But $2520$ is an acceptable multiple so we need no larger.

Comment: Thank you all, now it s more clear.